# webservice error: The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding

Tags: c#, web-services, service-reference

I created C# project and add a "web service" as a "Service Reference".
my service almost allways works good, but sometimes, occures this error:

> The content type text/html of the response message does not match the
>   content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a
>   custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is
>   implemented properly. The first 13 bytes of the response were:
>   `'<HTML></HTML>'`.

I google this error, but i didnt find anything related to this
all my search results relates to WCF

most important point on this error is "response were: `'<HTML></HTML>'`"
client expect "xml response", but server response an empty "html response"

Could you please advice what could be wrong?

[edited]
my code is very simple:

```
webserv.Insert_ImageSoapClient myservice = new webserv.Insert_ImageSoapClient();
string response = myservice.insert_x(station_id_x, time_t);
```

Comment: we could advise a problem and solution much better if you supplied us with code where the error stems from ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the web service is erroring out and returning an HTML page.

Comment: maybe, but webservice respone is empty! <html></html>

Comment: Have you debugged the web service?

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler? That would tell you if the issue is the web service or the consumption thereof.

Comment: i still have not use fiddler, i dont think this is helpful

Comment: Well, if you are not willing to try all troubleshooting steps, I can't help you.